# Trie implementation using python - charToIndex

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, trie

I'm trying to refer the Trie implementation python code in link
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/

i'd a question regarding the following private method :

```
def _charToIndex(self,ch): 
        # private helper function 
        # Converts key current character into index 
        # use only 'a' through 'z' and lower case 

        return ord(ch)-ord('a')
```

How is this helping to get the index of the character i.e. by converting the character ch to Unicode,  subtracting from it - Unicode value of 'a'

pls help clarify.
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ord()` gives the Unicode code point (an integer).  The code points for `a`-`z` are consecutive, so `ord(ch) - ord('a')` gives the index of the character as an offset of `a`.  `ord('a') == 97`, so for example, `ord('b') - ord('a') == 1` and `ord('z') - ord('a') == 25`.

Answer (score 0):

I like the previous answer, but that's how it works, not why you do it. I think the intention is to use a list data structure, with 26 slots, to contain each node's child nodes. The function charToIndex converts an alpha to an int from 0 to 25 (hopefully), and you can check to see whether that child node exists or not, during add or search functions. It does beat using a list and possibly having to iterate through the whole list in order to find the one you want. It also may or may not beat a hashmap lookup for a child node, but the time difference would be minimal, I think. The list may speed up add and search functions, but not traversals... you still have to test all 26 child nodes during a traversal!